# Get size of folder and all contents for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have seen in several SAAS sites where people store data and the site tracks how much data is on their servers. They display that information to the user.

Using ruby on rails how do some of these sites do this? It seems like enough sites do it that there must be a standard way I am just not aware of. Or is it everyone pretty much implements their own solution?

If everyone has implemented their own solution then is this a good appraoch using:

```
`du -s <directory>`
```

and just parsing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du` is a very good tool for this sort of thing, it's probably faster than what you could roll by hand using [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/find/rdoc/classes/Find.html), but you'll need to be careful when parsing the output.

It's not uncommon for directories to contain exotic characters in their names which includes the obvious like spaces, and the unusual like newlines. This makes parsing the output of `du` somewhat unreliable if someone does this:

```
% mkdir "foo
1234     bar"
```

If that's not a big deal, forget about it. Otherwise you'll need to recurse and do the math manually, something that can take a while for the Ruby interpreter on large filesystems.

Comment: I marked this as the answer since `du` is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

All depends on how the site is storing the actual data, and meta-data about the objects that its users upload to it.  It is entirely possible that the  Data isn't being stored on a traditional file system (such as S3).  So in cases that like `du` wouldn't work.

So if you store the meta data in the database, including the size, you can just get the sum of the upload size via a query, and not have to have hit the underlying filesystem...

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, at all. That gives me more to think about. Thanks.

Comment: If using the file system for storing, something like `du` may be sufficient.  Remember, the amount of space a file takes up on disk may differ than the file size depending on the block size set on disk, hence the actual amount of true disk space is larger than the sum of the size of the individual files.

Comment: yeah the files were going to be on a filesystem so du looks to be my best option. I just had never even considered the thought of getting metadata and storing that. Its so simple an idea though I don't know why I didn't think of it. thanks.

Comment: Remember that du can be pretty intensive on the IO Subsystem, so you probably don't want to be running it all the time, and especially not on user demand, since you might run into performance issues pretty quickly that way..